# espress mongodb aggregation exclude docs by array of ids

Tags: mongodb, express, search

I have a search controller where I want to exclude some documents by an array of ids. Next is my aggregation:

```
var aggregation = [
            {
                $geoNear:{
                    query : {
                        //_id:{$nin:user.friends}, <---- user.friends is an array of id's that I want to exclude
                        "profile.age":{$gte: minAge, $lte: maxAge},
                        "approved":true
                    },
                    near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ user.location[0], user.location[1]] },
                    limit:100,
                    maxDistance:radius*1000,
                    distanceField: "dist.calculated",
                    includeLocs: "dist.location",
                    distanceMultiplier:1/1000,
                    spherical: true
                }
            },
            {
                $project:{
                    online:1,
                    promoted:1,
                    location:1,
                    profile:1,
                    dist:1
                }
            },
            { $sort : { online:-1, promoted:-1} }
        ];
```

How can I achieve that the result would exclude some doc's having an array 'user.friends' populated with the id's that needs to be excluded.
_id:{$nin:user.friends} is not working

Answer (score 0):

I would assume your array `user.friends` is an array of strings, So since it checks against the _id which is an Object, not a String, the query cannot work as you expect it to work.

So what you have to is to convert your array `user.fridns` into an array of Objects. Something like:

```
user.friends = user.friends.map(x => ObjectId(x) );
```